# Using Google charts with php data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-visualization

I've got a page in which i display some stats for various arrays passed from my contoller which are contained and displayed using `$var1[0] -> amount`, i have 3 different arrays which are all similar

```
$var1[0] -> amount
$var2[0] -> amount
$var3[0] -> amount
```

all of these relate to a figure pulled from different database tables and can be echo'd to display the figure.

i want to be able to get that number into the google chart to show pretty colours and a % but I'm having trouble porting the numbers into the charts.

i've tried

```
$data = array( 

             array('Type', 'Amount'),  

             array('HMRC', $hmrc[0] -> amount),  

             array('Apps', $apps[0] -> amount),

             array('Cheques',$cheques[0] -> amount) 

);



json_encode($data);
```

and then passing the $data into the google.visualization.arrayToDataTable without success.

is there a correct/official way to do this properly?

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        "<?php echo $data ?>"
        ];
```

Comment: the best way and let your work with other charts tool, is get json data from the server. Anothe one is using assosiative array for this like: array('Type'=> 'Amount', 'HMRC'=> $hmrc[0] -> amount, 'Apps'=> $apps[0] -> amount,'Cheques'=> $cheques[0] -> amount) and then use json_encode as response

Answer (score 0):

Google has a great example of how to [get server side code into the Google Charts here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example). Instead of the call you have, you should use this one:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
```

Comment: thanks for the help but now it says table has no columns, is that norml?

Comment: You aren't listing any columns in your data. Look at the sample data file on the link I put in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, not familiar with jSon or ajax so ill have to try and figure it out